# SendKeys.send is sending more than one character

Tags: c#, sendkeys

sorry for my bad english.

I am writing a keyboard application for the touchscreen. but,

for example, when I press the A key, sometimes it's writes 5 times A key . I am using basically button click event.

```
private void button42_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("A");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

there is no problem with the mouse_click event. just touch

how can i do it?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at your `Send` method and observe how many times the method is executed.

Comment: actually doing on some screens. I tested it. only one time executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346281/vb-net-sendkeys-letters-duplicate

Comment: Also, run without debugging on Release configuration

Answer (score -2):

1.Try handling it in a **mouse_up or touch_up** event instead of using a delay here. *Actual implementation and events will depend on you framework.*

mouse_up /touch_up will make sure that you even only fires when touch is released.

To add repetition on touch and hold, you may have to add additional logic however.

2. Try declaring a field to toggle the value of event fired.

   ```
    private bool handling=false;
    private void button42_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!handling)
        {
            handling=true;
            SendKeys.Send("A");
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
            handling=false;
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: i tried thread.sleep(5000) but not worked. it's waiting 5 seconds and writing more than one.

Comment: Don't use Thread.Sleep() in your UI thread. It blocks everything and that is always bound to give strange results.

Comment: Yes, Using Task.Delay() is better always. Also you can try disabling the control on click and enable only after some time has passed. 
Also post some details on what is the control that you are using for your keys.

Comment: any idea? I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: you did not answer whether you are using buttons or other control.

Comment: @CodeNameJack ohh sorry. I tried Task.delay(2000). i wrote Messagebox.show("Test") first line in Button_Click event. only one messagebox showing me but writing more than one character.

Comment: Have you tried putting task.Sleep() before your touch event as the first line in your method.

Comment: I have added one more logic. you can try that maybe.